# Seeking an efficient way (no scraping) to get details about all the SEDE queries in non-HTML (JSON / XML / etc.) format

Tags: support, data-explorer

I am looking for an efficient way to get a dump of the current revisions of (preferably all) the [SEDE queries](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries), in a format which is natively queryable (such as XML / JSON). For each query, I ideally need the following attributes:

- Query description
- Actual SQL query itself
- Parameter information if any
- View count for the query
- "Favorite" count

Note: the results of the queries themselves are NOT required.

I would like to do this without having to scrape and parse the individual HTML pages for each query. I have looked at related questions on meta.SE, but did not find any efficient way to do this.

I did find a related effort [here](https://github.com/hirupert/sede) but a) that is an older snapshot, and b) it does not have useful attributes like view count and upvotes for the queries.

Comment: Your question seems to be missing a couple of words in the first sentence, but could also benefit from some additional clarification. You are talking about the actual SQL queries themselves? (Pretty clear after visiting the link, but the question itself should be clear.)

Comment: Just to spare anybody else from making the same investigation I just did, the weekly [data dump](https://archive.org/download/stackexchange) does not include `data.stackexchange.com`

Comment: "All information" implies every revision, but I imagine you might be better served by getting only the most recent revision of every query.

Comment: @tripleee - thanks. I have edited my question to reflect your comments. And yes, the latest revision of each query, would be adequate for my purposes.

Comment: Maybe you can also clarify what your purposes are? Do you want to build some kind of "Stack Exchange Data Explorer Explorer", or a list of fun statistics facts about SE, or are you writing a scientific paper, etc? This is partly because I'm just curious to know but partly also because it may be easier to suggest an approach if it is known what the end goal is.

Comment: "Without having to scrape" implies using the API; have you looked into that? Or are you hoping somebody else already did the work (in which case this should perhaps be closed as a recommendation request)?

Comment: If its for research purposes, I wonder if contacting SE directly would make sense.

Comment: Re: intent: my question came after reading this [this blog post](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/05/how-to-fake-load-tests-with-sqlquerystress/) and [associated gist](https://gist.github.com/BrentOzar/12b8ac33a67f02f413d30529caff5676). I was curious what else we can explore if we look beyond the dozen or so queries that were shown in the blog post / gist. Research ideas include detecting SQL (anti-)patterns at scale, code reuse (or lack thereof), potentially looking at revisions / forks to determine collaboration, etc. Hence, having a dump of the query corpus would be helpful.

Comment: @tripleee - I did look at the [API documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) but there is no API (at least I cannot find any) for SEDE itself. If I missed something, please clarify.

Comment: @Arvind - no, you did not miss anything, the official API does not have anything SEDE-related, unfortunately (might make for a nice feature request, though). Nor is there anything of sorts available for the project itself to my knowledge. The suggestion by Journeyman Geek does make sense in this light - SE might be willing to share a dump with you if you describe your use case convincingly enough to them